# Are any of these jpa annotation values redundant?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm reading through [this tutorial](https://kielczewski.eu/2014/12/spring-boot-security-application/) and was whether any of the annotation values defining the primary key are redundant?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Long id;
```

In other words could the author just have:

```
@Id
private Long id;
```

And get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the annotations are *redundant*.  Each of them influence very specific behavior, depending upon the needs of your domain model.

- @Id
  This annotation identifies a property/field that should participate in the entity's primary key.
- @GeneratedValue
  This annotation allows specifying how the value of the property/field should be derived.  Should this annotation be omitted, the value is assumed to be provided by the application.
- @Column
  This annotation describes the schema representation of the property/field, specifying the name, characteristics about its insertion, updatability, and nullability settings, etc.  By omitting this annotation, the persister provider will use a series of default values to represent the database schema representation of the property/field.

Ergo, in your former example, the identifier value will be derived by an AUTO_INCREMENT or IDENTITY representation at the database level and will be mapped to a field named "id" which is not null.

In the latter example, the identifier value is assumed to be provided, thus it must be set before persisting the entity.  The exclusion of the `@Column` annotation is irrelevant in this specific case because Hibernate will use a column named after the property name, thus a field "id" will be used.  Primary keys are by default not nullable and not updatable.